# How to set custom warning with validation in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

If validation fails, so id is not `githubid1`, or `githubid2` then I would show a custom message like `Please set an existing GihHub ID`. Is it possible to set it?

```js
<FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mb: 6 }}>
  <Controller
    name="username"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      validate: (v) => { // <-----------
        return v == "githubid1" || v == "githubid2";
      },
    }}
    render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
      <TextField
        value={value}
        label="Username"
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="johndoe"
        error={Boolean(errors.username)}
      />
    )}
  />
  {errors.username && (
    <FormHelperText sx={{ color: "error.main" }}>
      {errors.username.message}
    </FormHelperText>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [customError, setCustomError] = useState('');

<FormControl fullWidth sx={{ mb: 6 }}>
  <Controller
    name="username"
    control={control}
    rules={{
      validate: (v) => {
        if (v !== "githubid1" || v !== "githubid2") {
          setCustomError('Your custom text here');
        }
        
        return v == "githubid1" || v == "githubid2";
      },
    }}
    render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
      <TextField
        value={value}
        label="Username"
        onChange={onChange}
        placeholder="johndoe"
        error={Boolean(errors.username)}
      />
    )}
  />
  {errors.username || customError && (
    <FormHelperText sx={{ color: "error.main" }}>
      {errors.username.message || customError}
    </FormHelperText>
  )}
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Seems good, but `validate` does not get called at all when I type in values. Do you see maybe why?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74127483/why-custom-validate-not-get-called-with-react-hook-form

Comment: I don't know which framework you are using here and how <Controller /> works. Try to read theirs docs and search for custom validate function or something like that.

You can also try to console.log(v) and check what value it has.